# @ActionMapping Fails to Redirect to View

Tags: spring, forms, liferay

Asked on Liferay Forum post [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/75391575)

I have a Spring form that updates user information on submit. The form should redirect the user back to the form after saving, along with any success/error messages regarding their inputs to the form.  My problem is I cannot get the `@ActionMapping` to redirect back to the `form` view. I followed the guide [here](http://proliferay.com/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-portlet/) but haven't had any luck.

```
@ActionMapping(params ={"action=saveUser"})
public void saveUser(
    @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
    BindingResult result,
    ActionRequest actionRequest,
    ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException {     
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form");
    try {
        userRepo.save(user);
        mav.addObject("success", "User successfully saved");
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "success");
    } catch (Exception e){
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "failure");
    }
}


@RenderMapping(params = "action=success")
public ModelAndView viewSuccess() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form");
    mav.addObject("success", "stuff");
    return mav;
}

@RenderMapping(params = "action=failure")
public String viewFailure() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form");
    mav.addObject("failure", "other stuff");
    return mav;
}
```

After the user is saves successfully the `viewSuccess()` method should be invoked and return the form, but it is never called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the mentioned tutorial than you are missing the following line

```
<action-url-redirect>true</action-url-redirect>
```

in `liferay-portlet.xml` under your portlet

Comment: I've included this in liferay-portlet.xml but it didn't have any affect on my redirect

Comment: What about `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` (this too in `liferay-portlet.xml`), this is a shot in the air :p